# Unable to execute command inside double square brackets inside my Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
clean:
    @for container_name in ${NEW_DJANGO_IMAGE_NAME} \
                           ${NEW_MSQL_IMAGE_NAME} \
                           ${NEW_NGINX_IMAGE_NAME} \
                           ${NEW_REDIS_IMAGE_NAME}; \
        do if [[ 'a' == 'a' ]]; then echo 'fdfdf'; fi; done;
```

If I do something like this it works. Now instead of this silly line

`do if [[ 'a' == 'a' ]]; then echo 'fdfdf'; fi; done;`

I want to write the following:

`do if [[ docker ps --filter "name=^/$$container_name$$" --format '{{.Names}}' == $$container_name ]]; then echo 'fdfdf'; fi; done;`

The idea is that I iterate over a number of docker containers and if it happens that some of them are running I want to stop them. So in the place of `echo 'fdfdf'` I want to see this line: `docker container stop <CONTAINER_NAME>;`
Looks as simple as hell but I can't get it to work in the Makefile...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't escape `$$container_name$$` properly.  The `$$` will evaluate to `$` before being passed to bash, and then bash will see `$container$` as a variable and try to expand it...   I'm thinking you want `$$$$container_name$$$$`

Comment: @HardcoreHenry That's not the right escaping.  If you want to escape something from the shell you have to use shell escaping, not makefile escaping.  You want this: `"name=&/$$container_name\$$"` (note the backslash before the second `$$`)

Comment: For those of us unskilled at docker, could you show the bash conditional that works on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You apparently think that `[[ cmd == "string" ]]` executes `cmd` before performing the test. This is not the case. Use:

```
[[ `cmd` == "string" ]]
```

instead. In your case it would look like this:

```
do if [[ `docker ps --filter "name=^/$$container_name$$" --format '{{.Names}}'` == $$container_name ]]; then docker container stop $$container_name; fi; done;
```

Or, a bit more readable, maybe:

```
IMAGES := $(NEW_DJANGO_IMAGE_NAME) $(NEW_MSQL_IMAGE_NAME) \
          $(NEW_NGINX_IMAGE_NAME) $(NEW_REDIS_IMAGE_NAME)

clean:
    @for cn in $(IMAGES); do \
       tmp=`docker ps --filter "name=^/$$cn$$" --format '{{.Names}}'`; \
       if [ -n "$$tmp" ]; then \
         docker container stop $$cn; \
       fi; \
    done
```

Note that, in this last version, we use the bourne shell `test` commmand (`[`) instead of the bash-only conditional expression (`[[...]]`).